# Is there way to get `invalidated` flag from `Results` object?

Tags: swift, realm

I am using Realm Swift.

I have an object `Post` that has relation `comments` to `Comment` objects:

```
final class Post: Object {
    var comments: List<Comment> = List<Comment>()
}
```

... and then I create `Results<Comment>` object by transforming it from `List<Comment>`:

```
let results = post.comments.filter(NSPredicate(value: true)).sorted("creationDate")
```

... and it works perfectly until I delete original `Post` object.

When I delete `Post` object and call `results.count`, Realm crash with this advice: `IMPORTANT: if you see this error, please send this log to help@realm.io.`.

So I understand why it is crashed but **how can I handle this situation when I have only `results` object and it suddenly becomes invalid**.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in Realm, which is being tracked as https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3054. Subscribe to that issue to follow progress on a fix.